# Lando tooling command syntax

Tags: yaml, wp-cli, lando

I'm trying to set up a some tooling in my .lando.yml file to rapidly accomplish several tasks I do on every fresh Wordpress install. Everything's working great except for if I try to use the `[--extra-php]` option in the wp-cli and syntax as demonstrated in the wp-cli docs.

I get the following error when I run the command: `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

If I remove the code beginning at `<<PHP` and ending at the closing `PHP`, everything executes perfectly.

I assume I need to escape the parentheses in some way, but how to properly do that in YAML? Though I don't specifically get a YAML, so I'm not sure if that's actually the issue either.

**Relevant section of config:**
*The error occurs at the first parenthesis.*

```
tooling:
  npm:
    service: node
  wp-install:
    service: appserver
    cmd:
      - wp config create --dbname=wordpress --dbuser=wordpress --dbpass=wordpress --dbhost=database --extra-php <<'PHP' 
        define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); 
        define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); 
        define( 'ACF_PRO_LICENSE', 'XXX'); 
        PHP      
      - wp core install --url=http://$LANDO_APP.$LANDO_DOMAIN --title=XXX --admin_user=StudioAl --admin_password=XXX --admin_email=kerri@studioal.com
      - wp plugin install gravityformscli --activate
      - wp gf install --XXX --activate
      - wp plugin install "http://connect.advancedcustomfields.com/index.php?p=pro&a=download&k=XXX" --activate
```

**Stock example of usage of the problem code in documentation for wp-cli, for reference**

```
# Enable WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG
$ wp config create --dbname=testing --dbuser=wp --dbpass=securepswd --extra-php <<PHP
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
PHP
Success: Generated 'wp-config.php' file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A YAML parser loads this:

```
  - wp config create --dbname=wordpress --dbuser=wordpress --dbpass=wordpress --dbhost=database --extra-php <<PHP 
    define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); 
    define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); 
    define( 'ACF_PRO_LICENSE', 'XXX'); 
    PHP
```

as a sequence with a single item that is a string **which doesn't have any newlines**. That is something like:

```
["wp config create --dbname=wordpress --dbuser=wordpress --dbpass=wordpress --dbhost=database --extra-php <<PHP define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); define( 'ACF_PRO_LICENSE', 'XXX'); PHP"]
```

If that string is handed to a (Unix) shell, it will IMO not interpret that as an [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) because the delimiting identifier (`PHP`) doesn't occur on a line of its own.

You might have more success if you make that scalar a literal style scalar by inserting a pipe symbol before the scalar:

```
  - |
    wp config create --dbname=wordpress --dbuser=wordpress --dbpass=wordpress --dbhost=database --extra-php <<PHP 
    define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); 
    define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); 
    define( 'ACF_PRO_LICENSE', 'XXX'); 
    PHP
```

that way the string is loaded include the newlines (but without leading spaces)

Comment: Ah, it was the line breaks, not the parenthesis itself! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Found this great explanation that goes into detail on YAML line breaks. Most accurate bullet point midway through: "YAML is crazy." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-in-yaml-over-multiple-lines